# Virtuemart : Product not adding to cart

Tags: joomla, virtuemart, cart

I have a joomla site (J2.5) running and I am using virtuemart v2.0.6

I edited the css of product details and deleted a few codes (quantity box). However, when I click add to cart button, product is not getting added to the cart.

I am stuck from past few days.

Here is the link : http://www.kidsrule.com.au/index.php/shopping-deals/view/productdetails/virtuemart_product_id/2/virtuemart_category_id/1.html

Thanks!

Comment: try to undo the changes you made or provide us the code for more clarification

Comment: I have undone the changes. You can see the quantity box now. It shows 1 as the quantity. Also, initially when code was not edited, it was displaying quantity different than the one selected in quantity box.

Comment: Thi sis what im getting on clicking this link http://awesomescreenshot.com/0c86m2hcd  and URL is this -- http://www.kidsrule.com.au/index.php/component/users/?view=login  --> The place is for registered users only :)

Comment: Sorry about that. Please try now. http://www.kidsrule.com.au/index.php/shopping-deals/view/productdetails/virtuemart_product_id/6/virtuemart_category_id/1.html

Comment: "jQuery is not defined" --> Remove JS Errors

Comment: that's because virtuemart jQuery makes button unusable. Check now. It have enabled it but add to cart button no longer works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11811/discussion-between-swapnesh-and-akshat-goel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through your site and found some js error. Either your remove js error or change the add to cart setting in virturemart configuration.At the moment you have selected  Use Ajax to add, update or delete products from the cart? and the Ajax is not working due to js error, so you might changes this option to No. Then add to cart will not use the Ajax method to add product in the cart.Co can change the option in Configuration>>site>>Layoyt>>Configuration....
I am using some older version of joomla and virtuemart so the option may be in different place.


And to remove js error you can use jQuery.noConflict and replace the symbol $ with jQuery.
Hopefully this will help you..

Comment: Thanks Pramod. Unfortunately, this bug is from virtuemart side. I saw a post on their forum. facebox has not been defined error is common for all. I have removed the ajax addition to cart and now it redirects to that page, but product addition is still not there. Can you check the link again? I have disable jQuery and ajax scripts from configuration.

Comment: ya i have gone through the site.This problem is from virtue mart side.It may be possible that you have remove the code which add product in the cart, so it will be good to replace all the files which you modify with the default files and then check whether this is working fine or not.

Comment: opps ...The last thing which you can take the backup of the whole project and then reinstall the virtuemart.IF this does not work then you should try older version of the virtuemart.

Comment: yeah will have to discuss with the client on that one. Thanks for the help though. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can also add your product using the link even in any article or using html anywhere like this.:

```
index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.cart&func=cartAdd&product_id=56&quantity=3
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing virtuemart errors in version 2.0.6 , switch to Virtuemart 2.0.2. It's more reliable.